# DPAPI NG - NCryptProtectSecret returns NTE_ENCRYPTION_FAILURE

Tags: windows-server-2012-r2, dpapi, cng

I am trying to encrypt data using DPAPI-NG but it fails on execution of **[NCryptProtectSecret](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/hh706802(v=vs.85).aspx)**, it returns:

> 0x80090034 (NTE_ENCRYPTION_FAILURE)

I have created **[NCryptCreateProtectionDescriptor](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/hh706800.aspx)** with local user SID:

```
"SID=S-1-5-21-2942599413-360359348-3087651068-500"
```

Then I use this instance of descriptor as input for **[NCryptProtectSecret](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/hh706802.aspx)**, but it does not work.

If I use a protection descriptor of:

```
"LOCAL=user"
```

everything seems okay, but it does not work with SID for user or group. I have tested this on Windows Server 2012R2 and Windows Server 2016.

Any idea?

Here is a code sample:

```
SECURITY_STATUS Status;
PBYTE       ProtectedData = NULL;
ULONG       ProtectedDataLength = 0;
NCRYPT_DESCRIPTOR_HANDLE    DescriptorHandle = NULL;
LPCWSTR ProtectionDescString = L"SID=S-1-5-21-2942599413-360359348-3087651068-500";

Status = NCryptCreateProtectionDescriptor(
                                        ProtectionDescString,
                                        0,
                                        &DescriptorHandle
                                        );      
// Status is ERROR_SUCCESS (zero)


LPCWSTR SecretString = L"Some message to protect";
PBYTE Secret = (PBYTE)SecretString;
DWORD SecretLength = (ULONG)( (wcslen(SecretString)+1)*sizeof(WCHAR) );

Status = NCryptProtectSecret(
                        DescriptorHandle,
                        0,
                        PlainText,
                        PlainTextLength,
                        NULL, // Use default allocations by LocalAlloc/LocalFree
                        NULL, // Use default parent windows handle.
                        &ProtectedData,  // out LocalFree
                        &ProtectedDataLength
                        );

**// Status == NTE_ENCRYPTION_FAILURE**
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I ran into this problem and found that the cause was our domain was running at a functional level that was less than 2012.  After upgrading the domain to 2012 the problem was resolved.

A quick and easy way to determine the functional level is the following PowerShell cmdlet

```
[system.directoryservices.activedirectory.Forest]::GetCurrentForest().ForestMode
```

Comment: I do not have the system with the issue anymore :) But since this maybe was a problem at that time, I will mark this as the answer. It can be more useful than my one. Thanks for sharing this.

Comment: I **am** able to encrypt using domain SIDs; and our Windows Server 2012 domain controller is running in **ForestMode** in `Windows2003Forest`

Answer (score 1):

Replace PlainText and PlainTextLength with Secret and SecretLength.

Comment: Hi Miksha. That was a copy-past mistake. It is Secret and SecretLength as you said.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't figured out what was the problem, but everything worked fine in different domain. Microsoft also confirmed that working example that we have sent to them was correct, but they didn't explain what was be the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Check that the user running the application really *is* user

```
S-1-5-21-2942599413-360359348-3087651068-500
```

You can test this from and command prompt:

```
>whoami /user

USER INFORMATION
----------------

User Name     SID
============= ============================================
erbium\zeljko S-1-5-21-2942599413-360359348-3087651068-500
```

I got the `NTE_ENCRYPTION_FAILURE` when i was attempting to use a Group SID that i didn't actually have (the `Domain Users` group).

It might be you simply have the wrong sid compared to who is running the code.